# file cleanup using sed and regex (remove some but not all newlines)

Tags: regex, sed

i have a text file that i would like to load into hive. it has linebreaks within a string column so it won't load properly. from what i found out online the file needs to be preprocessed and all those linebreaks be removed. i have tried many regexes so far, but to no avail.

this is the file:

```
/biz/1-or-8;5.0;"a bunch of
text
with some

linebreaks in between.";2016-11-03
/biz/1-or-8;2.0;"more

text
here.";2016-10-18
```

the desired output should be this:

```
/biz/1-or-8;5.0;"a bunch of text with some linebreaks in between.";2016-11-03
/biz/1-or-8;2.0;"more text here.";2016-10-18
```

i could achieve this in notepad++ by using this as a regex: `(\r\n^(?!\/biz\/))+`

however, when i run that regex using sed like so it doesn't work:

`sed -e 's/(\r\n^(?!\/biz\/))+//g' original.csv > clean.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, `sed` doesn't support lookaround assertions such as `(?!\/biz\/)`.

Since your input is essentially *record*-oriented, `awk` offers a convenient solution.

With *GNU* `awk` or Mawk (required to support multi-character input record separators):

```
awk -v RS='/biz/' '$1=$1 { print RS $0 }' file
```

- `RS='/biz/'` splits the input into records by `/biz/` (reserved variable `RS` is the input-record separator, `\n` by default).
- `$1=$1` looks like a no-op, but actually *rebuilds* the input record at hand (`$0`) by normalizing any record-internal runs of whitespace - including newlines - to a single space each, relying on `awk`'s default field-splitting and output behavior.

  - Additionally, since `$1=$1` serves as a *pattern* (conditional), the outcome of the assignment decides whether the associated *action* (`{ ... }`) is executed for the record at hand.
    For an empty record - such as the implied one *before* the very first `/biz` - the assignment returns `''`, which in a Boolean context evaluates to false and therefore skips the associated block.
- `{ print RS $0 }` prints the rebuilt input record, prefixed by the input record separator; `print` automatically appends the output record separator, `ORS`, which defaults to `\n`.

<sup>Note: Your code references `\r\n`, i.e., Windows-style CRLF line breaks. Since you're trying to use `sed`, I trust that the versions of the Unix utilities available to you on Windows transparently handle CRLF.

If you're actually on a Unix platform and only happen to be dealing with a Windows-originated file, a little more work is needed.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you;

```
 sed -n '/^\s*$/d;$!{ 1{x;d}; H}; ${ H;x;s|\n\([^\/biz]\)| \1|g;p}'
```

test ;

```
$ sed -n '/^\s*$/d;$!{ 1{x;d}; H}; ${ H;x;s|\n\([^\/biz]\)| \1|g;p}' test
/biz/1-or-8;5.0;"a bunch of text with some linebreaks in between.";2016-11-03
/biz/1-or-8;2.0;"more text here.";2016-10-18
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` doesn't support lookarounds, `perl` does

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/(\n^(?!\/biz\/))+//mg' original.csv 
/biz/1-or-8;5.0;"a bunch oftextwith somelinebreaks in between.";2016-11-03
/biz/1-or-8;2.0;"moretexthere.";2016-10-18
```

- `-0777` option will slurp entire file as single string
- `m` option allows to use `^$` anchors in multiline strings

Note, line endings in Unix like systems do not use `\r`, but if your input does have them, use `\r\n` as specified used in OP.

Use different delimiter to avoid having to escape `/`

```
perl -0777 -pe 's|(\n^(?!/biz/))+||mg' original.csv
```

Another way to do it is delete all `\n` characters between a pair of double quotes

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's|".*?"|$&=~s/\n//gr|gse' ip.txt 
/biz/1-or-8;5.0;"a bunch oftextwith somelinebreaks in between.";2016-11-03
/biz/1-or-8;2.0;"moretexthere.";2016-10-18
```

- `s` modifier allows `.*` to match across multiple lines and `e` modifier allows to use expression instead of string in replacement
- `$&=~s/\n//gr` allows to perform substitution on matched text `".*?"`

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue! (with multi-char RS support)

```
$ awk -v RS='\n?^/' 'NF{$1=$1; print "/" $0}' file
```

or

```
$ awk -v RS='\n?^/' 'NF{$1="/"$1}NF' file
```

Comment: to restrict matching perhaps replace "/" with "/biz" both in RS and script.

Answer (score 0):

Create files

```
$ cat biz.awk
{ # read entire input to a string `f' (skips newlines)
    f = f $0 
}

END {
    gsub("[^^]/biz/", "\n/biz/", f) # add a newline to all but the
                                    # first /biz/
    print f
}
```

and

```
$ cat file
/biz/1-or-8;5.0;"a bunch of
text
with some

linebreaks in between.";2016-11-03
/biz/1-or-8;2.0;"more

text
here.";2016-10-18
```

Usage:

```
awk -f biz.awk file
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk. With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='"[^"]+"' -v ORS= '{gsub(/\n+/," ",RT); print $0 RT}' file
/biz/1-or-8;5.0;"a bunch of text with some linebreaks in between.";2016-11-03
/biz/1-or-8;2.0;"more text here.";2016-10-18
```